Redis client is closed
I get an issue using Redis with NodeJS.
I have an init function in my project to initialize ExpressJS APP and the Redis client.
My code :
function init(options) {
  var controllerFilePath,
    view = this;

  this.app = express();
  this.app.cacheService = redis.createClient();
  this.app.cacheService.on('error', err => console.log('Redis Client Error', err));
  this.app.cacheService.on('connect', () => {
    console.log('Connected to Redis12345'); // it work's I see the log
  });
}

And I'd like to use the Redis Client in my CacheLogic classe :
var CacheLogic = Object.create(null);

CacheLogic.getItems = getItems;


async function getItems(request, model, key) {
  var redisClient = request.app.cacheService,
    nodeCacheObj = model.options.nodeCache.find(nodeCacheObj => nodeCacheObj.key === key),
    fct = nodeCacheObj.fct,
    existingKey = await redisClient.existsAsync(key);

  if (existingKey) {
    return JSON.parse(await redisClient.getAsync(key));
  }

  return fct().then(function (items) {
    redisClient.set(key, JSON.stringify(items));
    return items;
  });
}

But I get the error :
    C:\wamp64\www\Gestiaweb\node_modules\@redis\client\dist\lib\client\index.js:510
            return Promise.reject(new errors_1.ClientClosedError());
                                ^

    ClientClosedError: The client is closed
        at Commander._RedisClient_sendCommand (C:\wamp64\www\Gestiaweb\node_modules\@redis\client\dist\lib\client\index.js:510:31)
        at Commander.commandsExecutor (C:\wamp64\www\Gestiaweb\node_modules\@redis\client\dist\lib\client\index.js:190:154)
        at BaseClass.<computed> [as get] (C:\wamp64\www\Gestiaweb\node_modules\@redis\client\dist\lib\commander.js:8:29)
        at RedisStore.get (C:\wamp64\www\Gestiaweb\node_modules\connect-redis\lib\connect-redis.js:32:19)
        at session (C:\wamp64\www\Gestiaweb\node_modules\express-session\index.js:485:11)
        at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\wamp64\www\Gestiaweb\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
        at trim_prefix (C:\wamp64\www\Gestiaweb\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:328:13)
        at C:\wamp64\www\Gestiaweb\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:286:9
        at Function.process_params (C:\wamp64\www\Gestiaweb\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)
        at next (C:\wamp64\www\Gestiaweb\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:10)
        at C:\wamp64\www\Gestiaweb\node_modules\request-ip\lib\index.js:139:5
        at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\wamp64\www\Gestiaweb\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
        at trim_prefix (C:\wamp64\www\Gestiaweb\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:328:13)
        at C:\wamp64\www\Gestiaweb\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:286:9
        at Function.process_params (C:\wamp64\www\Gestiaweb\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)
        at next (C:\wamp64\www\Gestiaweb\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:10)

    Node.js v20.10.0

